# AngularJS Limit the length of a string on textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one textbox that is autocomplete textbox. I mean when I type 3 character it automatically show me the related data about 3 characters.

I want that If I select value longer that 31 characters is cut off after select and display characters 1 to 28, add 3 dots (...)

And I want to Add a tooltip with the full value on mouse-over on textbox.

**html code**

```
<form name="orgForm" ng-submit="validateOrg(orgForm)" novalidate>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <section class="main-ctr">>
                <div ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>
                <main>
                    <section class="fix-section" style="min-height: 0px;">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-wrap">
                                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="orgName" class="form-input" ng-model="organization.name"
                                    placeholder="Enter your organization name..." required typeahead-min-length='3'
                                    uib-typeahead="state for state in orgList | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control"
                                    tooltip="asdasdasd" tooltip-trigger="{{{true: 'mouseenter', false: 'never'}[myForm.username.$invalid]}}" />
                                <div class="error" ng-show="orgForm.$submitted || orgForm.orgName.$dirty || orgForm.orgName.$touched">
                                    <span ng-show="orgForm.orgName.$error.required">Required Field</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <div class="button-ctr">
                        <button class="button" ng-class="orgForm.$valid ? 'active' : 'disable'" type="submit">Validate
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller code**

```
.controller('verifyOrgCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$http', 'dataServices', 'globalService', function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $http, dataServices, globalService) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        window.history.forward();
    });
    $scope.orgList = [];
    dataServices.getOrgList().then(function (res) {
        if (res.status) {
            $scope.orgList = res.orgList;
        } else {
            $rootScope.serviceErrorMsg = res.error;
            $state.go(res.redirectURL);
        }
    });
    $scope.organization = {};
    $scope.validateOrg = function (formName) {
        $scope.formName = formName;
        if ($scope.formName.$invalid) {
            $scope.showErrorMsg = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}])
```

Please help me to do this.

I am using AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

try using the limitTo filter

{{ myTxt | limitTo: 28}}{{ myTxt.length > 28 ? '...' : ''}}

Comment: Where I should write this?

Comment: i was thinking to put it inside the attribute value of your input but that will already change the value itself. what you should do is assign it to another variable so the value won't change after selecting from the autocomplete.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what you want to say. Can you please write some code regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a directive that forbide the user to type more characters than the maximum defined.

I adapted it a bit to your needs (length and "..." when max-length is exceed):

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('maxLength', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
                if(inputValue === undefined) return '';

                var cleanInputValue = inputValue.substring(0, 31); // Change max
                if(cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                    return cleanInputValue + '...';
                } else {
                    return cleanInputValue; 
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

You can use it like this:

```
<textarea ng-model="myTextarea" maxLength></textarea>
```